# PayPal Recurring Payment Using Credit Card

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I want to accept Recurring payments in PayPal using credit card. I have created seller and buyer account in sandbox. I have updated seller account to pro account also. Simple Recurring payment with PayPal account is working fine. I want to implement Recurring Payment with and without PayPal account. But its not showing me with credit card option.

Please let me know how to fix this or is there any alternative option for it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears there is some technical issue with your subscription button.
Add one sample code for your reference or you could refer to the integration guide [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/).

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXX@XXX.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="TMC membership fee">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1001">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="a2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t2" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="3.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I did the same thing. Created new button and used your code also, but i am getting same error. Is there any configuration required in seller's account for this?

Comment: I don't think so. would you please provide your button code and sandbox account here for my testing?

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake in  using sellers account. I had created seller account directly in paypal sandbox and using it. Now i am using seller account from developer website and using it. Its working for me. Thanks for your efforts.